# Find $\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac {\sqrt{x+3}-2}{\sqrt{x+8}-3}$.

Tags: limits, radicals

> Find $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 1}\frac {\sqrt{x+3}-2}{\sqrt{x+8}-3}$.

I tried to rationalize it, but doesn't help either. Please give me some hints. Thank you.

Comment: How about multiplying by the conjugate.

Comment: How did you rationalize it?

Comment: @jasoncube you could see Calvin's answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275990/calculate-undersetx-rightarrow7-lim-frac-sqrtx2-sqrt3x20-sqrt/276012#276012

Comment: Divide the numerator and denominator each by $x$ and you get a limit with a numerator and denominator that are derivatives of two different functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\frac {\sqrt{x+3}-2}{\sqrt{x+8}-3}=\left(\frac {\sqrt{x+3}-2}{\sqrt{x+8}-3}\frac {\sqrt{x+3}+2}{\sqrt{x+8}+3}\right)\frac {\sqrt{x+8}+3}{\sqrt{x+3}+2}
$$

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using heavy artillery. Denote $y=x-1$ for convenience. We need to find
$$
\lim_{y \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{4+y}-2}{\sqrt{9+y}-3}.
$$
Not you just need to use the fact
$$
\sqrt{a^2+y} = a + \frac{y}{2a} + o(y)
$$
when $y \to 0$.

Comment: I have never used this approach when rationalising radical limits. $(+1)$ :D