# How can I determine limit: $\lim\limits_{x\to4}\frac{x-4}{x-\sqrt[]{x}-2}$?

Tags: real-analysis

How can I determine limit:

$$\lim_{x\to4}\frac{x-4}{x-\sqrt[]{x}-2}$$

Thanks

Comment: Please don't use display math (`$$..$$`) in the title of your question. It breaks the main page.

Comment: isn't it just $0$? are you sure you wrote the right question?

Comment: The problem is that there is no problem!  The bottom is well-behaved near and at $4$.

Comment: My suspicion is that the problem is intended to be $\lim_{x \rightarrow 4} \frac{x - 4}{\sqrt{x} - 2}$; that's a more typical limit question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are unfamiliar with L'Hopital's rule, this is what you can do.

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 4} \frac{ x - 4 } { x - \sqrt{x} - 2} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 4} \frac{ (\sqrt{x} - 2) ( \sqrt{x} + 2) } { (\sqrt{x} -2) ( \sqrt{x} +1) }=  \lim_{x \rightarrow 4} \frac{ ( \sqrt{x} + 2) } { ( \sqrt{x} +1) } = \frac{ 4}{3}.$$

Comment: Great! -- I hadn't consider factoring it...

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Factorization would almost always work. See [this other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275990/calculate-undersetx-rightarrow7-lim-frac-sqrtx2-sqrt3x20-sqrt/276012#276012) as a great example of what to do.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the denominator tends to $4-\sqrt{4-2} = 4-\sqrt2$ as $x \to 4$ and the numerator tends to $0$ as $x \to 4$.

**EDIT**

The answer to the new question is as follows.
We have
$$\dfrac{x-4}{x-\sqrt{x}-2} = \dfrac{(\sqrt{x}+2)(\sqrt{x}-2)}{(\sqrt{x}-2)(\sqrt{x}+1)} = \dfrac{2+\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}} \,\,\,\,\, \forall x \neq 4$$
Now take the limit as $x \to 4$.

Comment: Ha ha ha! Rats! Not relevant :)

Answer (score 2):

Write $t=\sqrt x$, now we can write the limit as:

$$\lim_{t\to 2}\frac{t^2-4}{t^2-t-2}=\lim_{t\to2}\frac{(t-2)(t+2)}{(t-2)(t+1)}=\lim_{t\to 2}\frac{t+2}{t+1}=\frac{2+2}{2+1}=\frac43$$

Comment: Ha ha ha! Rats! Not needed :)

Comment: @user17762: Who's laughing now? :)

Comment: Its because the OP changed the question.

Comment: @user17762: Well, that's besides the point! :-)

Comment: lol! :) ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

Let $h=x-4$ then
$$\frac{x-4}{x-\sqrt[]{x}-2}=\frac{h}{h-\sqrt[]{h+4}+2}=\frac{h}{h-2\sqrt[]{1+h/4}+2}\sim_0\frac{h}{h-2(1+h/8)+2}=\frac{4}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

The post has been edited, now the solution is easy if you apply L'Hopital rule:
$$\lim_{x \to 4} \frac{x - 4}{x - \sqrt{x} - 2} = \lim_{x \to 4}\frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}} = \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{2\sqrt{4}}} = \frac{4}{3}$$

Comment: It looks like the expression has settled down, so this is a good place to use LHR (I tried looking for a "conjugate factor" approach, but I don't see a tidy one...).

Comment: @RecklessReckoner You should be using factorization instead. Works much better, and is the approach most students are familiar with.

Comment: Actually, in my experience at this point in the semester, most students would use the "hammer" of l'Hopital...

Comment: I think so too...